# ArrayList of type item cannot hold values from a file

Tags: java, arraylist

I am supposed to read from a file, sort it into an Arraylist and then search for it.

But when I read the file and attempt to fill my Arraylist it gives me a cannot be applied to java.string error.

Also I am having trouble figuring out how to sort this list.

This is what I am pulling the numbers from : http://puu.sh/pn9hs/abd4980197.png

```
public class storeDalton {
Scanner in;
private ArrayList<Item> myStore = new ArrayList<Item>();
Item product;

public storeDalton(String fName) {

}

public storeDalton() {
}

private void loadFile(String inFileName) {
    try {
        in = new Scanner(new File(inFileName));
        while (in.hasNext()) {
            myStore.add(in.nextLine());
        }
    } catch (IOException i) {
        System.out.println("Error: " + i.getMessage());
    }
}

public void displayStore() {


}

//  public String toString() {

//  }

public void Sort() {

}


private void merge(ArrayList<Item> a, int first, int mid, int last) {

}

public void mergeSort(ArrayList<Item> a, int first, int last) {

}

private void swap(ArrayList<Item> list, int a, int b) {
}


public static void main(String[] args) {
    storeDalton run = new storeDalton();
    run.loadFile("file50.txt");
    run.displayStore();

}
}
```

Comment: Create an Item object first with the String you read in, then add **that** to the ArrayList.

Comment: Please, be clear as to what you're intending to do. What exactly is your problem? Try to explain that, instead of asking "how to do that" questions. This ensures the problem (and possibly any given solution) are clear and may be re-used by other users.

Comment: It's best to always post the full error and/or stack trace.

Answer (score 1):

If you look at your code you will see that there is the code,

```
ArrayList<Item> myStore
```

This means that the ArrayList will contain objects of type `Item`

You are trying to add Strings - this will not work.  Try to constrcutor `Item` Objects and add them?

Answer (score 0):

When declaring the list variable, you have provided `Item` as the generic type, but you are attempting to store a `String` inside the list. You will need to convert the string to an `Item` somehow and store that in the list instead.

```
ArrayList<Item> myStore; // Here you are saying that the list will store Item objects
...
myStore.add(in.nextLine()); // But here you're trying to store a String object
```

Answer (score -1):

```
public Item(int id, int inv){
    myId = id;
    myInv = inv;
}
```

Ok I think I figured it out I need to split my string into two parts and then convert to int values.

Comment: No way for us to guess this as you never posted your Item class code. The bottom line is to read the error messages critically, to believe them and to act on them. They already have told you that you're likely trying to add a String an ArrayList that only accepts an Item object.